# perl: restrict perl from automatically creating a hash branches on check

Tags: perl, hash, build-automation

*(Regarding the duplication: the pointed discussion is related, but different in target:  that author looking for a way to find all places of such occurrences, while I know all of them, but looking for a way to avoid such behavior! Therefore, while it is educational to read that 'duplication', this question is different!)*

My issue is that the perl script (as I have done it so far) creates empty branches when I try to check some branches on existence.

I am using multidimensional hashes: found it as the best way for information that I need to handle.
Saying multidimensional I means hash of hashes ...
So, I have

```
$hsh{k1}{k2}{k3}{k4}=v1;
$hsh{k1}{k9}{k3}{k33}=v2;
....
```

In some point I need to check some 'set of keys' on existence in the hash.
So, I check:

```
if ( $hsh{ch1}{ch2}{ch3} ) {  ...something... }
```

And, suddenly I've realized, that such check creates the intermediate branches to access the final one for checking!

So, if there is no `$hsh{ch1}` before the check, it will be created to access the key 'ch2', which will be created to access the 'ch3'

**QUESTION:**  ***Is there a way to avoid such aromatic creation ????***

Logically, I would expect the Perl to get FALSE as soon as any key is not exist in the hash, but it is not happening!

Sure I could do:

```
if ( $hsh{ch1} && $hsh{ch1}{ch2} && $hsh{ch1}{ch2}{ch3} ) 
{...}
```

but it is so annoying, especially when I have many hashes with 7- 10 keys!

I have creates some function to check a hash 'reasonably', sending hash reference and array of keys to be checked, and it works fine, but it is slows down the processing visibly.

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
  DB<4> $h{a}{b}=[1,2]; $h{a}{c}=[3,4]  #hash with two elements (arrays) and in 2 levels

  DB<5> use Data::Dumper  #good way to display 

  DB<6> p Dumper\($a,%h)
$VAR1 = \undef;
$VAR2 = {
          'a' => {
                   'c' => [
                            3,
                            4
                          ],
                   'b' => [
                            1,
                            2
                          ]
                 }
        };

  DB<7> p 'da' if !$h{p}{m}  #checking for an existent keys and element
da
  DB<8> p Dumper\($a,%h)
$VAR1 = \undef;
$VAR2 = {
          'p' => {},            # <<== created one !!!
          'a' => {
                   'c' => [
                            3,
                            4
                          ],
                   'b' => [
                            1,
                            2
                          ]
                 }
        };

  DB<9> delete $h{p}
```

**Once again: *Is there a way to avoid such behavior without creating additional function?***

Answer (score 3):

Use the [autovivification](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/VPIT/autovivification-0.14/README) module from CPAN.

Comment: Thanks, it would be good, if I could install any CPAN: not my system...
---
 I have some replies on 'Perl Guru' forum [(Perl-Guru-my-post)](http://perlguru.com/gforum.cgi?post=80149;sb=post_latest_reply;so=ASC;forum_view=forum_view_collapsed;;page=unread#unread) and, I believe, there is nothing more need to be discussed on that issue.
---
 Thank, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
use autovivification;

no autovivificaiton; # disable perl's autovivification feature from this point

if ( $hsh{ch1}{ch2}{ch3} ) {  ...something... }
```

see [autovivification](https://metacpan.org/pod/autovivification#SYNOPSIS) module